# Is there a way to tell from the HttpServletRequest if a request is via a Apache AJP connector or direct

Tags: servlets, tomcat9

Is there a way to tell from the HttpServletRequest if a request is via a Apache AJP connector or direct

```
   <Connector port="8443"
               scheme="https" secure="true" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="8000" acceptCount="3000" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxConnections="10000" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol">
             ...
    </Connector>

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" />
```

The senario we have is some users access tomcat via the internet on which access is

webaddress:8443 --> pointed by firewall to intranet apache:443 --> AJP connector to tomcat:8009

when on intranet the customer admin has mapped the webaddress to the tomcat so that

webaddress:8443 --> tomcat:8443

so the broswer URL is same webaddress:8443 so from the URL cant tell if its via apache or direct to tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Found a way by setting header in apache

RequestHeader set PROXY_HEADER APACHE

then detect PROXY_HEADER in HttpServletRequest.getHeaders